# Microsoft SQL analysis Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

> How can i retrive Microsoft SQL Analysis Server  Properties using SQL Query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis services does not use SQL Query.  It uses MDX.
Properties are stored in XML files.

You may be able to run a powershell script to get info.  Here is a snap-in to enable SSAS queries in powershell - http://powerssas.codeplex.com/